# jquery only appends last item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to append multiple audio tags to the body of a document using `jQuery`:

```
$(function () {
    var a = $("<div/>").text("hello");
    $("body").append(a);
    a.text("world");
    $("body").append(a);
});
```

why isnt `var a;` being appended twice?  I would at least expect "world" to appear twice (I understand I am overwriting "hello").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the element in the `a` variable is already appended to the `body`, so the second line causes no change.

If you want two elements appended, you would need to create a second manually, or `clone` the first one:

```
$(function () {
    var a = $("<div/>").text("hello");
    $("body").append(a);
    a.text("world");
    $("body").append(a.clone());
});
```

Comment: Something like: `a.clone(true).text("world").appendTo("body");` -- And here ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/c9JyW/

Comment: So jquery keeps track of what elements have already been appended?  Does it keep a cache of this?

Comment: @Mike_G no, it is repeating the `append`, but the element is already where you are placing it, so it appears nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, but how does jQuery "know" that element has already been appended?  There has to be some sort of comparison made right?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, jQuery keeps track of which elements are in the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

basically you already inserted a div from one instance a variable

example: **http://jsfiddle.net/kdKV8/4/**

you could try cloning it.. clone()

```
$(function () {
    var a = $("<div/>").text("hello");
    $("body").append(a.clone());
    a.text("world");
    $("body").append(a);
```

});

**http://api.jquery.com/clone/**

Answer (score 0):

**this might be easier...**

```
$('body').append($('<div/>').text('Hello'), $('<div/>').text('World'));
```

made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/filever10/Hh9hq/

Answer (score 0):

you can also tried below code

```
$(function () {
        $("body").append($("<div/>").text("hello"));
        $("body").append($("<div/>").text("world"));
    });
```